# Sort ArrayList in ascending order and giving a character priority (Java)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, comparator

I want to sort an ArrayList in ascending order but want to keep items starting from a character (for eg: say 'S') on top. I am trying to achieve this using Comparator.

```
Collections.sort(mSearchHolder.get(1).contactList, new Comparator<SearchData>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(SearchData s1, SearchData s2) {
                    int returnValue = 0;
                    if(!s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())
                            && !s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                        returnValue = s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
                    } else if(s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())
                            && s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                        returnValue = s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
                    } else {
                        if(s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                            returnValue = 1;
                        } else if(s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                            returnValue = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    return returnValue;
                }
            });
```

It's not working. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: what's not working? what's the expected output and what output did you get?

Comment: What should be the output for "aa" and "as"?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flip the -1 and 1 return cases.

If only s1 matches S, then s1 is before s2, so return -1.

If only s2 matches S, then s2 is before s1, so return 1.

```
Collections.sort(mSearchHolder.get(1).contactList, new Comparator<SearchData>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(SearchData s1, SearchData s2) {
                    int returnValue = 0;
                    if(!s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())
                            && !s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                        returnValue = s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
                    } else if(s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())
                            && s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                        returnValue = s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
                    } else {
                        if(s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                            returnValue = -1;
                        } else if(s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                            returnValue = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    return returnValue;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public class TestSort {

    static String search = "S";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SearchData> searchCollection = new ArrayList<SearchData>();
        searchCollection.add(new SearchData("Sting"));
        searchCollection.add(new SearchData("Maria"));
        searchCollection.add(new SearchData("Sarah"));
        searchCollection.add(new SearchData("Andrea"));
        searchCollection.add(new SearchData("Sergio"));
        searchCollection.add(new SearchData("Gustav"));

        Collections.sort(searchCollection, new Comparator<SearchData>() {

            public int compare(SearchData s1, SearchData s2) {
                String s1name = s1.getName().toLowerCase();
                String s2name = s2.getName().toLowerCase();
                String searchLower = search.toLowerCase();
                int returnValue = 0;
                if (!s1name.startsWith(searchLower)
                        && !s2name.startsWith(searchLower)) {
                    returnValue = s1name.compareTo(s2name);
                } else if (s1name.startsWith(searchLower)
                        && s2name.startsWith(searchLower)) {
                    returnValue = s1name.compareTo(s2name);
                } else {
                    if (s1name.startsWith(searchLower) && !s2name.startsWith(searchLower)) {
                        returnValue = -1;
                    } else if (!s1name.startsWith(searchLower) && s2name.startsWith(searchLower)) {
                        returnValue = 1;
                    }
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
        });

        for(SearchData s : searchCollection) {
            System.out.println(s.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

It gives the output:

```
Sarah
Sergio
Sting
Andrea
Gustav
Maria
```